# Can I get .deb packages for LXDE?

Tags: 12.10, apt, deb, lxde

Is there any way I can download LXDE and all its related packages as .deb packages? I had done this with Synaptic but since there's no Synaptic on 12.10, can this be done with apt-get? Thanks

Comment: PPA for Synaptic with GTK3: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-install-synaptic-with-gtk3.html

Comment: Do you actually want to download the packages or install them? I interpreted your question to install them, but now the other answer came in I think you may just want to download them without installing. In that case, what is the purpose?

Comment: And what do you mean by "related packages"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily download LXDE and all the dependencies with apt-get.

- First, clean the cache.

  ```
  sudo apt-get clean
  ```
- Now, run the following

  ```
  sudo apt-get --download-only install lxde
  ```

The downloaded packages will be in `/var/cache/apt/archives`

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The Synaptic Package Manager is still available, just not installed by default (as has been the case for several releases). You can install [synaptic [image: Install synaptic]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic) in the Software Center or by running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

If you cannot install it, make sure the Universe [repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) component [is enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository).

Comment: +1 nice edit thanks i have installed it on new installation

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming OP wants to install the packages as well*

Just install the APT task to properly install LXDE for Ubuntu as Desktop environment like this:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop^   # the ^ is not a typo
```

Alternatively, use your favourite package manager (e.g. [synaptic [image: Install synaptic]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic), [muon [image: Install muon]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/muon)) or search in the Ubuntu Software Centre: [lubuntu-desktop [image: Install lubuntu-desktop]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lubuntu-desktop)

The LXDE desktop suite consist of a lot of packages and is not available as a single `.deb` file. Downloading them all separately and finding/satisfying all dependencies would be lot of work. Just let your package management handle this for you instead - it's exactly what it is designed for!

Comment: Please explain the function of `^` and what do you mean by "Just install the APT task"?

Comment: @vasa1 Remember good old `tasksel`? That's now regarded deprecated in favour of tasks in apt (at least, that's what another user told me here - looking for reference), selected by appending `^`. Other popular one is `lamp-server^`.

Comment: Quite ashamed to say I've never used `tasksel`! But I'll read up on it :)

Comment: I had a quick look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel.

Comment: @vasa1: [Should I use tasksel, tasks in APT or install regular metapackages?](http://askubuntu.com/q/252056/88802)

Comment: I think OP should clarify why .deb packages were specified. If it is just a matter of installing lxde then I would have thought that `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` would be the most user-friendly way to go. As I said, I've no experience at all with `tasksel` or even tasks in APT. And I don't know about servers either. All in all, OP needs to **come back and clarify**!