# Should I use tasksel, tasks in APT or install regular metapackages?

Tags: apt, package-management, tasksel, metapackages

#### Tasksel or plain Apt?

In the past I've always used `tasksel` to install so-called "tasks". It seems, however, that this has been integrated in APT:

```
apt-cache dumpavail | grep ^Task
[...] snip
Task: lamp-server
[...]
```

and that I can install such "tasks" by appending a caret (`^`) to it, like this:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Is this equivalent to the following?

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

And which is preferred?

#### Metapackages

Additionally, how do metapackages come into play here? Some tasks seem not to be a metapackage while others are:

```
apt-cache show lamp-server
N: Unable to locate package lamp-server

apt-cache show kubuntu-desktop
Package: kubuntu-desktop
[...]
Task: kubuntu-desktop
```

---

So, using the last example, what is the difference between the following three possible ways to install?

- `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`
- `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop^`
- `sudo tasksel install kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Look at the output of `apt-get install -s lubuntu-desktop` versus `apt-get install -s lubuntu-desktop^`. In the latter, you'll see something additional like this: Note, selecting 'policykit-1-gnome' for task 'lubuntu-desktop' / 
Note, selecting 'gnome-keyring' for task 'lubuntu-desktop' / 
Note, selecting 'libplist1' for task 'lubuntu-desktop' / 
Note, selecting 'aspell-en' for task 'lubuntu-desktop' / 
Note, selecting 'libsdl1.2debian' for task 'lubuntu-desktop' / 
 So, **in this particular case**, I'm not sure that the "carrot" one is any better.

Comment: More reading here: http://askubuntu.com/a/249373/25656

Comment: #warning about tasksel: **never** use it to remove tasks - see [bug report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/574287)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In short: There **is** a difference between tasksel and apt-get installation process of tasks.

Looking at your example:

### The apt-get way

`sudo apt-get install 'lamp-server^'` will evaluate to do the following:

1. Search the cache (package list files) for all "Task:" fields and get all with "lamp-server".
2. Install those packages the standard way:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install package1 package2...
   ```

### The tasksel way

`sudo tasksel install lamp-server` will look for a task called "lamp-server" in one of its configuration files under `/usr/share/tasksel/**/*.desc`:

1. Search the configuration files for a "Task:" field named "lamp-server".
2. Check if all prerequisites are available ("Key:" field) and remember them if not installed.
3. Choose method to select packages ("Packages:" field). If this ist "list" simply install following packages by name.
4. Read all following package names and pass it to previously selected method to generate package names.
5. Look for `/usr/lib/tasksel/info/lamp-server.preinst`. If it exists execute this script.
6. Install packages with apt-get using following command:

   ```
   debconf-apt-progress -- apt-get -q -y -o APT::Install-Recommends=true -o APT::Get::AutomaticRemove=true install package1 package2 ...
   ```
7. Look for `/usr/lib/tasksel/info/lamp-server.postinst`. If it exists execute this script.

### Conclusion

tasksel is more powerful in processing and selecting tasks. It can execute extra scripts before/after installation/removal of tasks. And the biggest benefit: You can modify tasks and create new ones very easily. It is not possible to edit an official package list file without drawbacks (valid signature).

Back to your first question:
In your special case both commands are almost equivalent (supposed you have enabled both `APT::Install-Recommends` and `APT::Get::AutomaticRemove`). Only difference is the extended package state of `mysql-server` and `apache2` dependencies (set to "manually installed" with plain apt-get).

### And what about metapackages?

If you don't make use of tasksel's features like selecting tasks (especially helpful at installation) and executing extra commands before and after some task blocks then a task is very similar to a metapackage. The difference is: A task is not registered as a package in APT cache.
So if you uninstall one task-dependency other task-deps aren't marked as auto-installed because they were explicitely installed. If you uninstall a metapackage the dependencies are removed with `autoremove` because their extended package state is "auto installed" (if not installed manually).
***Note:*** All distributed tasks in Debian install a metapackage named `task-TASKNAME`.

Giving your example:

1. `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

   - Will install the metapackage `kubuntu-desktop`. Dependencies are "auto installed".
2. `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop^`

   - Will select all packages tagged with task "kubuntu-desktop". That are all dependencies of metapackage `kubuntu-desktop`. They all are marked as "manually installed".
3. `sudo tasksel install kubuntu-desktop`

   - Make sure X is installed before installing packages of task.
   - Will install the metapackage `kubuntu-desktop`. Dependencies are "auto installed".