# How do I install the Unity desktop environment on Ubuntu Studio 13.04 (Xfce)?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-studio

I am a bit of a newbie.
I'd like to have the option of booting into either Unity of Xfce in Ubuntu Studio. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Install the [APT Task](https://askubuntu.com/q/252056/88802) `ubuntu-desktop`. Run

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^
```

(The caret at the end is not a typo.)

Then at the login screen you should be able to select the Unity session rather than XFCE, like this:

[image]

Comment: What does the caret at the end of the command signify?   Is it just part of the symbolic name and if so what convention is it following?

Comment: @AlanObject Click the very first link in my answer.

Comment: @AlanObject the caret at the end indicates it has to search for packages related to the _task_ named (in this case) "ubuntu-desktop". Follow [the link](http://askubuntu.com/q/252056/88802) mentioned by gertvdijk for a more detailed explanation.