# How to install the latest versions of LAMP componanents

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp

I want to develop web applications with PHP, for that reason I need to install a LAMP system, I heard that it's good idea to use latest versions of PHP, MySQL and Apache ... so if it's possible please help me ...

Comment: JFTR "I heard that it's good idea to use latest versions of PHP, MySQL and Apache ... so if it's possible please help me ..." - you heard it wrong.  It's probably safest to use the packaged versions in Ubuntu.  You will need the latest&greatest only in edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can install lamp server by just running,

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

(Please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/257172/117103) for an explanation.)

Then you can copy your files into /var/www folder and view through browser in localhost. Since copying files into /var/www folder needs privileges and annoying you can change that directory to your own one.

you can replace "/var/www" string in following files into your own directory path and then you can use new directory as your www folder.

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
```

After changing contents of the above files, run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

to restart webserver. Then you will be able to use new directory as the web folder.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Start by installing `tasksel`, then install the `lamp-server`. As per the [Ubuntu help documentation.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

- `sudo apt-get install tasksel`
- `sudo tasksel install lamp-server`

And you are off. Just place your files in `/var/www/`

go to `localhost` in a browser and view your files.