# What is "Task" in the output of "apt-cache show package_name"?

Tags: apt

When I run `apt-cache show inkscape`, the bottom of the output has:

```
Description-md5: fed6589659211fb40b80d03dda6e5675  
Homepage: http://www.inkscape.org/  
Description-md5: fed6589659211fb40b80d03dda6e5675  
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug  
Origin: Ubuntu  
Supported: 9m  
Task: ubuntu-usb, edubuntu-desktop-gnome, edubuntu-usb, ubuntustudio-video, ubuntustudio-graphics
```

But when I run `apt-cache show pdfgrep`, the line beginning with `Task` is absent:

```
Description-md5: 8c8a5397f782d81d957740280eb8f352
Homepage: http://pdfgrep.sourceforge.net/
Description-md5: 8c8a5397f782d81d957740280eb8f352
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

Why is the line beginning with `Task` present for some packages and not for others?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Task` field in your output means that the package is part of the task `edubuntu-desktop-gnome` for example.

This function is similar to that of meta-packages, and, in fact, **most** (but not all) of the tasks available from `tasksel` (task select) are also available as meta-packages.

To install `tasksel` type:

```
apt-get install tasksel
```

You can list all available tasks with this command (output stripped), but `tasksel` must be installed first:

```
root@host:~# grep 'Task\|Description' /usr/share/tasksel/ubuntu-tasks.desc
...
Task: minimal
Description: Minimal base system
...
```

You can also invoke `tasksel` as root by:

```
root@host:~# tasksel
```

[image: tasksel]

You may know this from the installation routine, because those "tasks" are normally installed during early system setup.

So, those packages in `apt-cache show` that have not the Task field (`pdfgrep` in your question) are not part of a task and will not be installed when you install a task via it's meta-package or `tasksel`. On the contrary `inkscape` is part of many different tasks, whose meaning you can find in `/usr/share/tasksel/ubuntu-tasks.desc`.

Comment: Strongly related to [package management - Should I use tasksel, tasks in APT or install regular metapackages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252056/should-i-use-tasksel-tasks-in-apt-or-install-regular-metapackages).