# What is the difference between mail-server^ task and the mail-stack-delivery package?

Tags: mail-server, metapackages

What is the difference between the `mail-server^` task and the `mail-stack-delivery` package?

Comment: Hey Paul, I don't want to migrate this (at least no yet) because I'm not entirely sure it is appropriate for [sf]. I'd hate to migrate good content only for it to be closed on the other site. You might ask in [their chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room). I also don't understand how Sylvain's answer didn't address your question. Perhaps you could edit it to expound on exactly what you want?

Answer (score 5):

Visit the mail-stack-delivery [package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/mail-stack-delivery) and download the [tar.gz](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dovecot/dovecot_2.1.7-7ubuntu3.debian.tar.gz) containing the Debian/Ubuntu packaging.

Open the `debian/control` file and look for lines beginning with `Provides:` like this one:

```
Package: dovecot-imapd
Architecture: any
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}, dovecot-core (= ${binary:Version}), ucf (>= 2.0020)
Provides: imap-server
Description: secure IMAP server that supports mbox, maildir, dbox and mdbox mailboxes
```

You can see that `dovecot-imapd` provides a package named `imap-server`, which is a virtual package, as defined in the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s-virtual_pkg):

> Sometimes, there are several packages which offer more-or-less the
>   same functionality. In this case, it's useful to define a virtual
>   package whose name describes that common functionality. (The virtual
>   packages only exist logically, not physically; that's why they are
>   called virtual.) The packages with this particular function will then
>   provide the virtual package. Thus, any other package requiring that
>   function can simply depend on the virtual package without having to
>   specify all possible packages individually.

**Edit**: `mail-server^` is not a metapackage, it's a **task** as defined in `/usr/share/tasksel/**/*.desc`

Apt can understand task if the "^" is appended to the task name but the installation process is a bit different from what tasksel is doing.

Visit [Should I use tasksel, tasks in APT or install regular metapackages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252056/should-i-use-tasksel-tasks-in-apt-or-install-regular-metapackages) for a complete description of both installation processes.

In terms of installed packages, you can easily dry-run `apt-get install` for both `mail-server^` and `mail-stack-delivery`:

```
sudo apt-get install -s mail-server^
sudo apt-get install -s mail-stack-delivery
```

The task `mail-server` will install:

```
bsd-mailx
dovecot-core
dovecot-imapd
dovecot-pop3d
libgpgme11
libpth20
libtokyocabinet8
mutt
postfix
procmail
ssl-cert
```

But `mail-stack-delivery` will install those packages instead:

```
dovecot-core
dovecot-imapd
dovecot-managesieved
dovecot-pop3d
dovecot-sieve
mail-stack-delivery
postfix
ssl-cert
```

I hope that answers your initial question.

Comment: This answer does not make it clear to me what the difference is between the `mail-stack-delivery` package and the `mail-server^` metapackage.

Comment: Where did you find the `mail-server^` metapackage, could you please add a link for reference?

Comment: [MetaPackages - Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) describes what a metapackage is, although it doesn't mention that, as I understand it, metapackages are one implementation in Ubuntu of [`tasksel`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel). I have seen the `mail-server^` metapackage in several articles describing how to set up and configure a mail-server.

Comment: My initial question was really very specific: what is the difference between `mail-server^` and `mail-stack-delivery`? You did a good job of identifying the differences in the installation processes, but I'm not clear what the difference is in what ends up installed on the server.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the packages installed by both methods.

Comment: When I have installed the packages on fresh installs of Precise, the configurations seem quite different, so the differences must go beyond just the packages that are installed. For example, `/etc/postfix/main.cf` is quite different in each installation. Using `mail-stack-delivery`, there is a file `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/01-mail-stack-delivery.conf` that doesn't exist on the server with `mail-server^`. These are just a few configuration differences that I have observed, so my question I think is more related to configuration differences than just packages installed.

Comment: In the case of `mail-stack-delivery`, you can [download the package](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dovecot/mail-stack-delivery_2.0.19-0ubuntu2.1_all.deb) yourself and extract it and look at the various scripts that run pre and post install and remove as well as the `01-mail-stack-delivery.conf` file you mention.