# Install website on localhost

Tags: localhost

I want to install a phpBB forum on my local host, but for that I need get something like IIS or XAMPP, PHP and SQL on my Ubuntu.

Can someone tell me how to do that?

---

Can I also get a tutorial how to CHMOD spefic files/maps?

Comment: IIS?! Xampp?! No. You need lamp. Here is all you need: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP Oh and it also covers "chmod" :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use tasksel, tasks in APT or install regular metapackages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252056/should-i-use-tasksel-tasks-in-apt-or-install-regular-metapackages)

Answer (score 3):

The following will show you how to setup LAMP, and install phpBB on Ubuntu 14.04 - Desktop X86-64 for the purpose of running it locally through http#://localhost/. If your goals are more advanced than that you will need to provide further clarifications in your post.

[Any urls I've typed that have a `#` after the http/https should not be typed. I just did that to bypass the max 2 urls limit, and the inability to post local host links.]

## Steps:

1. In terminal type "`sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`".
2. You will be prompted to pick a root password for MySQL.
3. In terminal type "`sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`".
4. You will be prompted to pick a web server; choose "apache2".
5. You will be prompted to configure database for phpmyadmin wiht dbconfig-common; choose "yes".
6. You will be prompted to provide the password for the database's admin user. Enter the password you previously choose for MySQL root.
7. You will be prompted to pick a password for phpmyadmin.
8. Open Mozilla Firefox, go to https://www.phpbb.com/downloads/ and download the .zip file for phpBB. [At this time the current version is 3.0.12.]
9. Navigate to where you saved it, the default is your Downloads folder, and extract the contents by right clicking and choosing "extract here".
10. Enter the folder that was extracted, select all, and copy.
11. In terminal type "`sudo -i nautilus`",browse to "`/var/www/html`", delete "index.html", and paste in the PhpBB files.
12. Right click on "config.php" and change the "others" settings to "read and write".
13. Open Firefox, and visit "http#://localhost/install/index.php". Click the "install" tab, "proceed to next step", and "start install".
14. In another tab visit "http#://localhost/phpmyadmin/". Login using "root" as the username, and the MySQL password you choose during installation.
15. Click on the "databases" tab, enter a name (eg: phpbb), and click "create". Under the tab "more" click "prividges", and the "add user". Enter a username, enter a password, and click "check all" for global permissions. Leave the other fields blank, and click "go" at the very bottom of the page. Logout of phpmyadmin.
16. In the first tab you can now enter you details. Being the name you choose for the database, the user name you just created, and the password for the user account you just created.
17. You will now setup a user account on PhpBB.

    screenshot 1: https#://copy.com/NRb3H93J4G1U
18. Now the "advanced settings" for which you can leave the default settings.
19. You will get a congratulations screen telling you that phpBB is setup.
20. In terminal type "`sudo -i nautilus`", and navigate to "`/var/www/html`". Delete the "install" directory.
21. You can now access phpBB from "http#://localhost/".

    screenshot2 = https#://copy.com/pqbNg62StakT

    screenshot3 = https#://copy.com/YlfAlkPRR6P6

## Notes:

- PhpBB requires some directories to have 777 permissions. By default these folders should already have these permissions, but if for some reason they don't you will need to manually change them. See the official installation guide for details regarding which folders to change: https://www.phpbb.com/support/documents.php?mode=install&version=3&sid=d113b3ae012cbd0d9e8c0736f8c9a02d#quickinstall
- Tested with Ubuntu 14.04 - Desktop X86-64 on May 31 2014
- Tested with Ubunty 16.04 - Desktop X86-64 on August 30 2016

Comment: Thanks, but: Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80

Comment: @Korkel Try rebooting your system (or even just restarting apache2 with <code>sudo service apache2 restart</code>).

Answer (score 0):

try this.
Install apache2 web server, php5, mysql DBMS and phpmyadmin like this

```
  sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 phpmyadmin
```

and you should have the core server software installed in your system. To deploy web pages, put them into the **www**  folder found like this.

```
 cd /var/www/ && ls #will display your contents in the browser.
```

Now you might try to start the server and get something like

**Could not reliably determine the server Path**

No worries. Just add this line below to your **apache2.conf**  file located in the /etc directory. To open this file type this command in your terminal.

```
 sudo nano /etc/apache/apache2.conf 
 #paste this line below somewhere in the middle of that opened file
 ServerName 127.0.0.1
```

Then restart your server like this

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now you can open your browser and type in **localhost**  better yet **localhost/phpmyadmin**

Remember, To deploy your web files, just dump them in the www folder described above. Ofcourse i skipped the password stuff while the dpkg installs mysql and dependacies.