# sudo nautilus error in 16.04

Tags: nautilus

I'm trying to set up localhost with [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474986/install-website-on-localhost)

Now at step 11 I'm supposed to open nautilus in terminal but whatever I do it throws some error at me.

I tried reinstall and update nautilus with no luck; the same errors appear after using `sudo nautilus`.

This is what the error looks like.

```
(nautilus:4594): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
(nautilus:4594): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
(nautilus:4594): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
(nautilus:4594): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(nautilus:4594): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu. I tried to google for the errors but without luck.

In Ubuntu I only replaced gnome network with wicd network manager

thanks in advance for any suggestions or help

Ivo

Comment: Do you have better luck running: `gksudo nautilus`? To install use: `sudo apt-get install gksu`

Comment: @andrew.46 `gksu` is depreciated use `sudo -i` instead.

Comment: @mchid Thanks, I did not know that...

Comment: It the bug number 1579160: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1579160

Answer (score 12):

These are not errors. These are warnings and all warnings are to be ignored.

With that said, you should use `sudo -i` to run gtk applications with sudo.

```
sudo -i nautilus
```

These warnings are normal and are to be ignored safely.

Although a fix is not necessary, there is a workaround.

The only work around requires you install the development files:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
sudo gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache
sudo killall nautilus
```

That should take care of most of the warnings.

If you don't like to see output in the terminal after running the command, you can use the nohup command like so:

```
nohup sudo -i nautilus
```

or

```
nohup sudo -i nautilus &
```

Again, in the future, you can ignore warnings like these unless there is a problem running the application.

Comment: sudo -i  nautilus will give me warning again , while doing it with gksu nautilus it works without a hitch . (nautilus:3310): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed       this is after doing all the updates that you posted

Comment: @IvoOlivieri That's just because `gksu` is non-verbose. Are you using ssh? If you are using `ssh`, sometimes you have to kill `nautilus` on the remote computer before using `ssh` to start `nautilus`.

Answer (score 0):

I found these warnings super annoying and didn't want to install multiple packages just to fix them. You can swallow command output by redirecting to a file:

```
nautilus ./myDirectory &> /dev/null
```

This would get really annoying to write every time, so I created a custom function in `~/.bashrc`:

```
 function naut() { 
    nautilus "$@" &> /dev/null 
 }
```

Which you can then use like so:

```
naut ~/Desktop
```