# nautilus crash after initialization

Tags: nautilus

When i open nautilus it works fine until i change the window to another application, then it crash.

I try to start nautilus from terminal to see what happens and this is the output:

```
arturo@toto:~$ nautilus

(nautilus:4110): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:4110): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:4110): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:4110): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:4110): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
arturo@toto:~$ ^C
```

I try this solution from [Nautilus not opening up, showing GLib error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788182/nautilus-not-opening-up-showing-glib-error)

```
arturo@toto:~$ ps aux | grep nautilus
arturo    1858  0.2  0.7 946456 59756 ?        Sl   10:20   0:06 nautilus -n
arturo    4176  0.0  0.0  16760  1012 pts/4    S+   11:12   0:00 grep --color=auto nautilus
arturo@toto:~$ sudo kill 1858
[sudo] password for arturo: 
arturo@toto:~$ nautilus -q
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2.10.0

** (nautilus:4181): CRITICAL **: Another desktop manager in use; desktop window won't be created

(nautilus:4181): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

also try purge and reinstall and nautilus remains the same.

also tried this [sudo nautilus error in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793844/sudo-nautilus-error-in-16-04)

with no succes

What can i do to have nautilus working just fine, i mean without crushing?

Comment: Could you [edit] the title and make clear what the question is? Thank you.

Comment: reboot & likely it'll be fine

Comment: @doug not solved