# What happened to the lamp-server metapackage on Wily?

Tags: lamp, 15.10

The Wily repo doesn't seem to have the `lamp-server` metapackage, and it may've been removed or replaced since earlier Ubuntu versions but I'm unaware since I've been a LEMH user for the past couple of years. (No official Wily repo for any of the LEMH components yet, hence my search for Ubuntu-shipped LAMP)

Can anyone enlighten me about `lamp-server`'s fate? Was it completely removed or replaced and since which version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no supported Ubuntu version containing a `lamp-server` meta-package. But you can ...

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

to search through `apt-cache` for the tasks `lamp-server` and install the packages in one step.

---

Example for `apt-cache show apache2`:

```
Package: apache2
Priority: optional
Section: web
…
Description-en: Apache HTTP Server
 The Apache HTTP Server Project's goal is to build a secure, efficient and
 extensible HTTP server as standards-compliant open source software. The
 result has long been the number one web server on the Internet.
 .
 Installing this package results in a full installation, including the
 configuration files, init scripts and support scripts.
Description-md5: d02426bc360345e5acd45367716dc35c
Homepage: http://httpd.apache.org/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 9m
Task: lamp-server, mythbuntu-frontend, mythbuntu-desktop, mythbuntu-backend-slave, mythbuntu-backend-master, mythbuntu-backend-master
```

---

Alternatively you can use `tasksel`:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

---

Read the great answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/257172/367165) for the differences.

Comment: To be accurate *no supported Ubuntu version* contains the `lamp-server` package. It did indeed exist, and I've installed it. But I do not know since which version it was removed.

Comment: Ok, changed my answer.

Comment: @Oxwivi nope. It has *never* been a package as such. It has been a task starting in edgy (6.10). You probably used aptitude, which handles tasks without extra syntax. Check: `for i in {breezy,dapper,edgy,feisty,gutsy,hardy,hoary,intrepid,jaunty,karmic}; do curl -s http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/$i/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2 | bunzip2 | grep -m1 lamp-server && echo $i; done`

Comment: @muru That's unpossible [sic]! I *know* I installed it. Sometime. Someplace.

Comment: It used to be a setup option before they started second guessing our needs. Oh, and tasksel is bloody dangerous. It can remove most of your installation with an uninstall. Now we just rely on scripts that may or may not be in GitHub.