# What replaced mail-stack-delivery?

Tags: postfix, dovecot, mail-server

Trying to install `mail-stack-delivery` on 19.10 Eoan I see it's now a transitional package that only installs `dovecot-core`. Before it used to install both Dovecot and Postfix and write a basic config connecting the two. Is there a newer replacement for it? I kinda wanted to avoid copy-pasting config chunks from wikis and askubuntu.com :-)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, such things are now implemented as something called "tasks" and can be installed either via their native control tool `tasksel`, or via `apt`. Here's more on the difference of these two variants: [Should I use tasksel, tasks in APT or install regular metapackages?](https://askubuntu.com/q/252056/340466)

`mail-stack-delivery` in particular seems to be served by the task `mail-server`, so:

```
sudo tasksel install mail-server
```

**Update**: The task however only install some relevant packages but doesn't do any configuration to tie them together, which is what was great about the old integrated package.

Comment: I got a `sudo: tasksel: command not found` when running `sudo tasksel install mail-server` on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @Aamnah this can be installed in turn with `sudo apt install tasksel`. Note however the update to my answer: the task doesn't really provide what I hoped it would.

Comment: thanks. i ended up manually installing the relevant packages and editing postman config..