# Any tips how to operate any web browser in Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, chromium

I installed Ubuntu (Jammy jelly fish) recently but I can not operate any web browser.

I used Firefox and Chromium but the VM froze when I tried to open any of these browsers.
I also tried to install Chrome but it doesn’t go through the installation.

Has Anyone faced this problem and how to fix it?

I use MacBook pro 8 GB ram, 256 GB memory and M1 processor.
Is there any link between the problem and my Mac features?

Comment: How exactly did you install Ubuntu on the Mac?

Comment: I used Ubuntu using virtual machine

Comment: I followed this video and it works well except the browser.  https://youtube.com/watch?v=1WWj6qoWhJw&feature=share

Comment: I can not operate, I meant can not open the browser at all and the virtual machine got frozen and I sometimes have to restart it

Comment: I am new in using linux, If I am wrong, could someone helping me to install it please? I am in need of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Virtual Machine on a Apple Silicon (M1) macOS Host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367423/ubuntu-virtual-machine-on-a-apple-silicon-m1-macos-host)