# ERROR When attempt to run Linux VM on Mac (VERR_UNSUPPORTED_CPU)

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, virtualization, cpu

My Ubuntu version is Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.2. My OS is macOS Monterey 12.2. I am a complete beginner to Linux and im trying to learn a bit more about it since it's a very in-demand OS. When I attempt to run the Linux Ubuntu VM on Virtual Box, I get this persistent error: Unsupported CPU (VERR_UNSUPPORTED_CPU Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE(0X800004005) Component: ConsoleWrap Interface: Console{6ac83d89-6ee7-4e33-8ae6-b257b2e81be8}. Since I am a beginner, I have no idea how to even go about fixing this error, and I believe that I will never learn Linux if I cant even get it to run on anything. If someone has any insight or has come across this error before and thinks they can be of assistance, Please help me out. I actually have NO idea what to do atm. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: its Ubuntu 22.02.2 desktop, VirtualBox version is Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 7.0.0. My OS is macOS Monterey version 12.2. For some reason when I try to start it, it gets 'aborted'?? If you need any more details please lemme know

Comment: Is your computer an Intel Mac or does it have the newer M series ARM-based processor?

Comment: I would have added more details but these are all the details that I can think of. Its not that I don't wanna be more detailed, I literally don't know what else to add. As for the the Ubuntu version, I have the most up to date version installed, Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Not 22.02.2, my bad). Do u need any more details than that?

Comment: @karel I believe its the latter, but im not too sure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Virtual Machine on a Apple Silicon (M1) macOS Host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367423/ubuntu-virtual-machine-on-a-apple-silicon-m1-macos-host) Apple's M series ARM-based processors do not support VirtualBox.

Comment: it's strange that you can install VirtualBox and everything works just fine but it only starts malfunctioning when you try to run (start) the actual VM. Like if its not supported you'd think that they wouldn't let u install it in the first place.... oh well, thanks anyways @karel

Comment: @guiverc my bad man, I said latest cuz I had just installed it today so I just assumed its the tastes version.

Comment: The latest version is macOS Ventura.

Comment: @karel is there an alternative for running linux on macOS Monterey (Apple Silicon M1) that you'd know of?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144992/discussion-between-karel-and-moataz-abdelraouf).