# Problem with VM on macOS Monterey 12.4

Tags: software-installation, virtualization, macosx, arm64

I'm trying to install a Linux virtual machine on a macOS Monterey 12.4 to take some courses on Udemy and I'm having a problem. I leave a link with a series of images (they may or may not be useful, but I leave it anyway).

[image]

The last print shows the login to which it does not go beyond. The steps I followed were from [here](https://mac.getutm.app/gallery/ubuntu-20-04). This guide is designed to only work with installing Ubuntu on Apple Silicon Macs.

I used UTM virtual machine software for Mac.

Comment: please [edit] to indicate how this refers to ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

[VMware Fusion 13 Player](https://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2022/11/fusion-13-pro-and-player-are-here.html) for Apple Silicon enables users to run Ubuntu Desktop (and Ubuntu Server) in a virtual machine that uses all the capability of the Apple M series processors' powerful integrated GPU to deliver near native performance on Apple silicon.

Fusion Player offers a [Personal Use License](https://customerconnect.vmware.com/en/evalcenter?p=fusion-player-personal-13), available for free with a valid CustomerConnect account. Home users, open source contributors, students, and anyone else can use Fusion Player free for non-commercial activity.

---

You can install an Ubuntu Server guest OS on an Apple silicon computer, and then install the complete ubuntu-desktop task in Ubuntu Server by running the following command:

```
sudo apt install 'ubuntu-desktop^'
```

Here are some additional tips for installing an Ubuntu desktop using VMware Fusion 13 player for macOS.

- Use the Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS ARM64 ISO to install an Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine.
- After the installation of Ubuntu 22.04 is finished convert the Ubuntu Server using the [tasksel](https://askubuntu.com/q/252056/) program which can be installed by `sudo apt install tasksel`. Install the Ubuntu desktop task by selecting it with the space key in tasksel and remove every server task that you don't want to keep.
- Install the open-vm-tools-desktop package in Ubuntu with `sudo apt install open-vm-tools-desktop`.
- You may need to disable kernel updates in Ubuntu.
- You may need to adjust the VM's settings to improve performance, especially the graphics performance which is great in macOS but in Ubuntu YMMV.