# I am trying to install Ubuntu 23.04 on my M2 Mac using VMware

Tags: system-installation, sudo, mac, 23.04, tasksel

I am trying to install Ubuntu 23.04 on my M2 Mac using VMware, but I can't get past the sudo command screen when I type in `sudo taskel install ubuntu-desktop` it keeps demanding I type in a command. I'd appreciate some help in navigating the sudo commands to install Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: What is your VMware software and what is its version?

Comment: VMware fusion 13 player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the complete ubuntu-desktop task in Ubuntu Server by running the following command:

```
sudo apt install 'ubuntu-desktop^'
```

Here are some additional tips for installing an Ubuntu desktop using VMware Fusion 13 player for macOS.

- Use the Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS ARM64 ISO to install an Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine.
- After the installation of Ubuntu 22.04 is finished convert the Ubuntu Server using the [tasksel](https://askubuntu.com/q/252056/) program which can be installed by `sudo apt install tasksel`. Install the Ubuntu desktop task by selecting it with the space key in tasksel and remove every server task that you don't want to keep.
- Install the open-vm-tools-desktop package in Ubuntu with `sudo apt install open-vm-tools-desktop`.
- You may need to disable kernel updates in Ubuntu.
- You may need to adjust the VM's settings to improve performance, especially the graphics performance which is great in macOS but in Ubuntu YMMV.

Comment: Thank you for the help, much appreciated.