How do I run the desktop after performing an upgrade to 24-04
Right, I've just done an upgrade as above and I found that when I restaated Ubuntu (as requested) all I got was a command prompt login. How do I go from this to the desktop - has anybody any ideas?

This question is similar to: How to fix broken 24.04.1 LTS upgrade which is missing necessary software?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: Switching between virtual console (tty) and GUI. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks - I've tried all the suggestions twice and still no joy. The problems seems to be an inability to resolve au.archive.ubuntu.com which results in a lot of missing files. Now what do I do?

If the repository is down, replace it with a working one.

Try running:
 sudo apt update

 sudo dpkg --configure -a

 sudo apt -f install

 sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

 sudo reboot


It needs to be ubuntu-desktop^

No, it has to be the system desktop, xfce, lxde, mate, etc.

It needs to have a caret ^. Please see https://askubuntu.com/a/257172/124466

Tried adding the "^" - didn't make any difference. Seems to be that au.archive.ubuntu.com is missing?
